# Convert List<T> to T item if there is only one element?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `List<>` with N items. I want to get the first element if and only if N = 1. Can this be done using `lambda` or some other nice construct?

This works, but looks horrible:

```
var blah = new List<Object>() { new Object() };
var item = (blah.Count == 1 ? blah[0] : null);
```

Comment: Your question would get a different meaning if you would replace _" only if N = 1"_ with _" only if Count = N"_

Comment: With your implementation, if there's only one item **and it's `null`**, the behaviour is indistinguishable from if there are 0 or 2+ items. Is this OK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several LINQ extension methods.

1. [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault)
    If there is one element it will be returned, if there are none `default<T>` will be returned, if there are multiple an exception is thrown
2. [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)
    If there is one element it will be returned, if there are none `default<T>` will be returned
3. [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx)
   returns the element at the given position or `default<T>` if the sequence has not so many elements

So for example (my preferred for your requirement):

```
var item = blah.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
```

---

The best method for your requirement depends on how strict this rule is:

> I want to get the first element if and only if N = 1.

If it's **exceptional** that there is more than one element in the sequence, use `SingleOrDefault` and you'll be informed (error-log) if it gets out of hand.

If it's important that you get the **first element** and you'll never want another element, use better `FirstOrDefault` because it has a meaningful name.

If the **index** of the element in the sequence is important and you (currently) need the first element, but that might change in future, use `ElementAtOrDefault`.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for it:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T SingleOrNothing<T>(this IList<T> list) where T : class
    {
        if (list.Count == 1)
            return list.Single();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Then you'd just call it in your code as such:

```
var item = someList.SingleOrNothing();
```

Comment: +1 for the approach. But you'll need to add a `class` type constraint, or better, return `default(T)` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I think SingleOrDefault is what you're looking for:

```
using System.Linq;    
...
var item = blah.SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: `Single` may be more appropriate in this case, if they want to ensure that there was an item.

Comment: This will throw an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look much better, but you can use `blah.Single()` instead of `blah[0]`:

```
var blah = new List<Object>() { new Object() };
var item = blah.Count == 1 ? blah.Single() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have :

```
var blah = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() };
```

you can do this :

```
var item = (blah.Count == 1 ? blah[0].Single<MyClass>() : null);
```